# Is there any way to get/buy the "Fate System Toolkit" book?

Tags: fate-core

I cannot find any way to buy/download the "Fate System Toolkit" book. I see that there was a kickstarter that would have granted me access to the book, but as far as I know, it is over now. I am too late! :(

So, does somebody know any way to buy/get a pdf copy of that book?

Comment: Isn't it not out yet, except for a draft version? I'm sure it will become available when it's done.

Comment: @okeefe Kyalur does say "different than waiting for the release."

Comment: I read that with the kickstarter they gave the book, but I don't know how finished it is. So probably is a draft, yeah :D

Comment: @gomad If being answerable by "a quick Google search" were reason to close a question, we'd lose a lot of questions. I believe we've firmly established that while lack of research makes for poor questions, it isn't itself close-worthy.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### It is available as a pay-what-you-like (including free) download.

Since Evil Hat recently made the Toolkit available under OGL, you can download the pdf from [rpgnow.com](http://www.rpgnow.com/product/119385/Fate-System-Toolkit) or [drivethrustuff.com](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/119385/Fate-System-Toolkit).

### It's also online!

You can access the Toolkit online as [part of the Fate Core System Reference Document](http://fate-srd.com/fate-system-toolkit/introduction).

Answer (score 5):

This product is now available on DriveThruRPG.com for a "pay what you want" price. Don't be one of THOSE people and pay a reasonable amount for it (I paid $10 and think I might have undersold it) but it's there now!

Answer (score 3):

### You can order it online at the Evil Hat web store.

The link is right here. Also, if you know anyone who has a PDF copy, you can ask them for a copy of it and they are quite allowed to give it to you: Fate Core, Fate Accelerated and Fate System Toolkit are [licensed under Creative Commons](http://www.faterpg.com/licensing/).

http://www.evilhat.com/home/fate-system-toolkit/